# Overwrite keycodes associated with arrow keystrokes

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I noticed that the keycodes associated with the arrows (up,down,left,right) changed, so the shortcuts defined for my terminal are broken.

I would like to change the keycodes of those values but I do not where I can modify them.
I read the current keycodes using `showkey -a`

| Keystroke | Desired Keycode | Actual Keycode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Arrow Up | ^[[A | ^[[1;1A |
| Arrow Left | ^[[D | ^[[1;1D |
| Arrow Down | ^[[B | ^[[1;1B |
| Arrow Right | ^[[C | ^[[1;1C |